# how would you go about writing this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to return records where the combination of column1 and column2 (in the table1) appear more than once

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2
from myTable
group by column1, column2
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: You know, technically if `column1` and `column2` aren't the only columns, you probably want to do this as a subquery as there might be more than one row with each combination, as this will only return the distinct groups, not the original records. You have my vote anyway, and this is almost certainly a homework question so OP can figure out that part.